# How Can I Make the `feedkeys` Function Run Silenty

Tags: functions

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433984/vimscript-generated-syntax-highlights-make-feedkeys-silent) post on Stack Overflow asking the same question but the response simply was "Don’t use feedkeys, here is a different solution."
Well I have a use case where I think I do need feedkeys.
Here is my function:

```
function! OpenCompletion()
    if !pumvisible()
        if (v:char == '/' || v:char == '$' || v:char == '~' || v:char == '.')
            call feedkeys("\<c-x>\<c-f>")
        elseif ((v:char >= 'a' && v:char <= 'z') || (v:char >= 'A' && v:char <= 'Z') || (v:char >= '0' || v:char == '0'))
            call feedkeys("\<plug>vim_completes_me_forward")
        endif
    endif
endfunction

autocmd insertcharpre * call OpenCompletion()
```

I want it to run the commands silently so that it doesn't show any messages at the bottom.
Also, apparently this is impossible with `feedkeys()`.
So I am trying to do it with `getcompletion()`.

Comment: please explain, what you mean with silently. What exactly do you want to hide?

Comment: I want to hide the messages that appear on the bottom of the window.

Comment: You can't really do that; `feedkeys()` is as-if you typed the keys yourself, in your case `<C-x><C-f>`. You can use something like `getcompletion('<cword>', 'file')`, maybe in combination with `complete()`, but it's not entirely clear what you want to do. But basically: if you don't want things to behave exactly like it would like you're using it from insert mode, then `feedkeys()` is the wrong choice.

Comment: I understand. How can I create a menu of the results `getcompletion()`? For example: `echo getcompletion('call ', 'cmdline')` will print to the screen but I want it in a popup menu instead. It is not clear from the documentation how to do this.

Comment: Something like `complete(col('.'), getcompletion('<cword>', 'file'))` I think, but I never used these functions before either so not 100% sure  It would probably be best if you would [edit] your answer to better describe what behaviour/goal you're looking for, because now that's a bit unclear to me, so hard to tell what the best option is. Also, you seem to be using VimCompletesMe, and maybe that already has a feature for this.

Comment: What I want to do is have an auto-complete function that makes suggestions as
you type (that would be for omni-completion and tags in the current file).
I accomplished this with `feedkeys()` but the problem is that it shows
messages at the bottom of the screen.
So now I am trying to do the same thing without `feedkeys()`.
I will edit my post to make it more clear.

Also, I tried this:

```vim
autocmd insertcharpre * call complete(col('.'), getcompletion('<cword>', 'file'))
```

But that gave me an error whenever I tried to type anything: "Not allowed
here".